# python - Sorting custom container objects

Tags: python, oop, list

In Python lists, there are two alternative ways of performing a list sort:

1. Using its `.sort` method, which sorts in place
2. Using the `sorted()` built-in function, which returns a new sorted list

Now, if I create a custom container type (say by subclassing from `itertools`'s ABC), can I do the same?

I can figure out how to make the custom container object sorts in place. But what I want is for the built-in `sort()` to return a new instance of that custom container object (instead of a list) when I use it.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Don't you mean [`collection`'s ABC](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just subclassing the builtin `list`, and just redefining `sort` method ?

```
>>> class MyList(list):
    def sort(self):
        copy = list(self)
        copy.sort()
        return MyList(copy)


>>> l2 = MyList([2, 6, 9, 8])
>>> l2
[2, 6, 9, 8]
>>> l3 = l2.sort()
>>> l2
[2, 6, 9, 8]
>>> l3
[2, 6, 8, 9]
>>>
```

EDIT: after the OP's comment, leaving `sort` method as is and adding a new one:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
    def sort_copy(self):
        copy = list(self)
        copy.sort()
        return MyList(copy)
```

The `sort` method inherited from parent remains as is (in place), the new `sort_copy` method creates a new one.

Comment: Hmm..this is possible, but then I'll lose the sort-in-place method. I'm trying to keep the two options (sorting in place and sorting to create a new object) available for my custom container.

Comment: Ok, then added a new method not in place.

Answer (score 1):

`sorted()` makes not a sorted container (with your type), but list:

```
class YourClass(...):
   ...
   def sort(self):
       new_data = self._data[:]
       ...sort new_data...
       return self.__class__(new_data) # new instance with sorted data
   ...
```

Comment: `sorted` does return a `list`, not just an iterator Also, if you sort `newdata`, `self._data` will be sorted also - they are the same object.

Comment: @WolframH, `sorted` does return a list - my fault. And `new_data` will be copied from `self._data`. Thank you for comment